# SdCard path correct path in android?

Tags: java, android, copy, onclicklistener, android-sdcard

I don't know if the problem is the incorrect sdcard path or something else, but in my application i have a button that onClick it create a copy of the `app` folder in the sdcard (of course needs root). To me it works, i have stock android 4.4 with nexus 5 and it creates a folder named `BackupApps` in where there is the folder `app` with all apk files but some users tells me that the folder is not created. Here the code:

first; i created the path in sdcard with the new folder that will created:

```
final File customfolder=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+File.separator+"BackupApps");
```

then the onClick code:

```
copy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            public void onClick(View v){        
                        Process checkroot = null;
                        String rootcheck ="su";
                        String cd = "cd /";
                        String comando ="su cd cp -av /data/app "+customfolder;
                        customfolder.mkdir();
                        try {
                            Process copy = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), appmanagerfragment.this.getResources().getString(R.string.toastcopysi), 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.v("All In One Copia tag","Ok, folder copied in "+customfolder);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }                  

        });
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think your `commando` is correct, becuse `su cd cp...` makes no real sense. You should remove `cd` from `commando`

Comment: Really strange.. Removing `cd` not works.. It creates the `BackupApps` folder but without apks inside..

Answer (score 0):

At first, there is a constructor for File, [File(String,String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), that adds the separator by itself.

At second, I'm not sure there's `su` in a non-rooted android. In addition, some command line keys may not be supported in Android, for example, `ls -l` works, but 'ls -lF' does not.
I suggest you run `adb shell` and perform the commands from the command line; when you know they do what you want, you move them to the code.

BTW, shell commands in the command line are separated with `;`.

In general, I if the task is to copy a directory, I suggest (pardon) searching google with "copy directory java" or "copy directory android stackoverflow" and borrowing someone else's code. For example, [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-copy-directory-in-java/) or [this](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.io/how-to-copy-a-directory-from-one-location-to-another-loc.html).
And add the permission to write to sd card to your application. (BTW, this may be the reason why the subprocess failed.)

Comment: i tried to change in: `String[] comando = {"su","-c", "cp -av /data/app "+customfolder};` maybe works.. to me in the nexus 5 yes.. now i try in my galaxy tab2.

Comment: doesn't work.. what do you suggest? In my adb works.. in the nexus 5 works..in the galaxy nexus for example not.. It creates the BackupApps folder but nothing's inside it

Comment: Nothing works using pure java.. I think shell via is the best way but i don't understand why on nexus 5 works and in other devices not.

Comment: "Nothing works using pure java" means that something is missing. You should have the exception trace in the log. It should have the description of the problem (btw, did you create the target directory?), like "no permission to do X". If you post the log...